# Copy Data from Web page and paste into Excel

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

I have been trying to **scrape** the web data using EXCEL VBA. Below code paste the date from excel to wen then initiated the submit button to go to the result page. which looks like this:

I want to copy and paste the first and the second line into excel like this:

if any individual gets first dose then put details of first dose, and return empty for the second dose if its empty. If both dose are not available then return empty for both.

I am not able to develop this last thing and struggling since couple of hours to achieve this (copy data and paste into excel)

it would required a ID number and date to submit for the result that i can provide in comments. I have been using following code to accomplish this your help will be much appreciated.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Newfunction()
    Const Url As String = ""
    
    Dim LogData As Worksheet
    Set LogData = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    
    Dim IdNumber As String
    Dim openDate As Date
    IdNumber = LogData.Cells(3, "A").Value
    openDate = LogData.Cells(3, "B").Value
    
    Set LogData = Nothing
    
    Dim ie As Object
    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

    With ie
        .Navigate Url
        
        Do While .Busy Or .ReadyState <> 4
            DoEvents
        Loop
        
        .Visible = True

        Dim ieDoc As Object
        Set ieDoc = .Document
    End With
        
    'Enter the CNIC
    Dim IDdata As Object
    Set IDdata = ieDoc.getElementById("checkEligibilityForm:cnic")
    If Not IDdata Is Nothing Then IDdata.Value = IdNumber
    Set IDdata = Nothing
    
    'Enter Date
    Dim puttdate As Object
    Set puttdate = ieDoc.getElementById("checkEligibilityForm:issueDate_input")
    If Not puttdate Is Nothing Then puttdate.Value = Format(openDate, "dd-mm-yyyy")
    Set puttdate = Nothing
    
    'Answering the captcha question
    'Split the innerText to string array to determine the equation
    
    Dim captchaQns As Object
    Set captchaQns = ieDoc.getElementsByClassName("submit__generated")(0)
    If Not captchaQns Is Nothing Then
        Dim mathEq() As String
        mathEq = Split(captchaQns.innerText, " ")
        Set captchaQns = Nothing
        
        'mathEq(0) = first number
        'mathEq(1) = math operator
        'mathEq(2) = second number
            
        If IsNumeric(mathEq(0)) Then
            Dim firstNum As Long
            firstNum = CLng(mathEq(0))
            
            If IsNumeric(mathEq(2)) Then
                Dim secondNum As Long
                secondNum = CLng(mathEq(2))
                
                'Select Case statement used here in case you encounter other form of math question (e.g. - X /), expand cases to cater for other scenario
                Dim mathAnswer As Long
                Select Case mathEq(1)
                    Case "+": mathAnswer = firstNum + secondNum
                End Select
            End If
        End If
            
        If mathAnswer <> 0 Then
            'Enter the answer to the box
            Dim captchaAns As Object
            Set captchaAns = ieDoc.getElementsByClassName("submit__input")(0)
            If Not captchaAns Is Nothing Then captchaAns.Value = mathAnswer
            Set captchaAns = Nothing
            
            'Get the submit button element, remove "disabled" attribute to allow clicking
            Dim submitBtn As Object
            Set submitBtn = ieDoc.getElementsByName("checkEligibilityForm:j_idt79")(0)
            submitBtn.removeAttribute "disabled"
            submitBtn.Click
            Set submitBtn = Nothing
        End If
    End If
    
    
    
    Dim tbls, tbl, trs, tr, tds, td, r, c
    
    Set tbl = ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("table")(0)
    Set trs = tbl.getElementsByTagName("tr")
    
    For r = 0 To trs.Length - 1
    
        Set tds = trs(r).getElementsByTagName("tr")
        'if no <td> then look for <th>
        If tds.Length = 0 Then Set tds = trs(r).getElementsByTagName("td")

        For c = 0 To tds.Length - 1
            ActiveSheet.Range("C4").Offset(r, c).Value = tds(c).innerText
        Next c
        
    Next r
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

It will enter the data into `Range("C4:F4")` for first dose and `Range("G4:J4")` for second dose.

```
Sub Newfunction()
    Const Url As String = "https://nims.nadra.gov.pk/nims/certificate"
    
    Dim LogData As Worksheet
    Set LogData = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    
    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = LogData.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Dim currentRow As Long

For currentRow = 3 to lastRow
    Dim IdNumber As String
    Dim openDate As Date
    IdNumber = LogData.Cells(currentRow, 1).Value
    openDate = LogData.Cells(currentRow, 2).Value
    
    Dim ie As Object
    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

    With ie
        .navigate Url
        
        Do While .Busy Or .readyState <> 4
            DoEvents
        Loop
        
        .Visible = True

        Dim ieDoc As Object
        Set ieDoc = .document
    End With
        
    'Enter the CNIC
    Dim IDdata As Object
    Set IDdata = ieDoc.getElementById("checkEligibilityForm:cnic")
    If Not IDdata Is Nothing Then IDdata.Value = IdNumber
    Set IDdata = Nothing
    
    'Enter Date
    Dim puttdate As Object
    Set puttdate = ieDoc.getElementById("checkEligibilityForm:issueDate_input")
    If Not puttdate Is Nothing Then puttdate.Value = Format(openDate, "dd-mm-yyyy")
    Set puttdate = Nothing
    
    'Answering the captcha question
    'Split the innerText to string array to determine the equation
    
    Dim captchaQns As Object
    Set captchaQns = ieDoc.getElementsByClassName("submit__generated")(0)
    If Not captchaQns Is Nothing Then
        Dim mathEq() As String
        mathEq = Split(captchaQns.innerText, " ")
        Set captchaQns = Nothing
        
        'mathEq(0) = first number
        'mathEq(1) = math operator
        'mathEq(2) = second number
            
        If IsNumeric(mathEq(0)) Then
            Dim firstNum As Long
            firstNum = CLng(mathEq(0))
            
            If IsNumeric(mathEq(2)) Then
                Dim secondNum As Long
                secondNum = CLng(mathEq(2))
                
                'Select Case statement used here in case you encounter other form of math question (e.g. - X /), expand cases to cater for other scenario
                Dim mathAnswer As Long
                Select Case mathEq(1)
                    Case "+": mathAnswer = firstNum + secondNum
                End Select
            End If
        End If
        Erase mathEq
        
        If mathAnswer <> 0 Then
            'Enter the answer to the box
            Dim captchaAns As Object
            Set captchaAns = ieDoc.getElementsByClassName("submit__input")(0)
            If Not captchaAns Is Nothing Then captchaAns.Value = mathAnswer
            Set captchaAns = Nothing
            
            'Get the submit button element, remove "disabled" attribute to allow clicking
            Dim submitBtn As Object
            Set submitBtn = ieDoc.getElementsByName("checkEligibilityForm:j_idt79")(0)
            submitBtn.removeAttribute "disabled"
            submitBtn.Click
            Set submitBtn = Nothing
        End If
    End If
        
    With ie
        Do While .Busy Or .readyState <> 4
            DoEvents
        Loop
        
        Set ieDoc = .document
    End With
    
    Dim resultTbl As Object
    Set resultTbl = ieDoc.getElementsByTagName("table")
    If resultTbl.Length <> 0 Then
        Dim resultRows As Object
        Set resultRows = resultTbl(0).getElementsByTagName("tr")
        
        If resultRows.Length > 1 Then
            
            'Get the 2nd row (1st row is header so ignore)
            Dim firstDose As Object
            Set firstDose = resultRows(1).getElementsByTagName("td")
                                    
            LogData.Cells(currentRow, 3).Value = firstDose(0).innerText
            LogData.Cells(currentRow, 4).Value = firstDose(1).innerText
            LogData.Cells(currentRow, 5).Value = firstDose(2).innerText
            LogData.Cells(currentRow, 6).Value = firstDose(3).innerText
            
            Set firstDose = Nothing
            
            'If there are totals of 3 TR elements then there are 2nd dose
            If resultRows.Length = 3 Then
                Dim secondDose As Object
                Set secondDose = resultRows(2).getElementsByTagName("td")
                
                LogData.Cells(currentRow, 7).Value = secondDose(0).innerText
                LogData.Cells(currentRow, 8).Value = secondDose(1).innerText
                LogData.Cells(currentRow, 9).Value = secondDose(2).innerText
                LogData.Cells(currentRow, 10).Value = secondDose(3).innerText
                
                Set secondDose = Nothing
            End If
        'Else
            'Do something here if there is only a header row i.e. no dose (assumption)
        End If
        Set resultRows = Nothing
    End If
    
   
    Set resultTbl = Nothing
    Set ieDoc = Nothing
    
    ie.Quit     'Remove if you don't want to close IE
    Set ie = Nothing 'Remove if you don't want to close IE
Next currentRow

Set LogData = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: @Valiant I didn't notice you want to paste from cell C4 in the original code so i have edited it. And I'm pasting back to `LogData` sheet so if thats not what you want, please change to the correct sheet

Comment: Unbelievable! thank you very much  @Raymond Wu you are truly gentle and genius one. One thing is still left that was to loop through entire data. It goes for 1 ID how to enable it to for the others ID's if the cell have. Yes i can change it thanks man.

Comment: @Valiant Gotta need more details.. how are the IDs and dates arranged in the worksheet? Is it 1 row = 1 ID and date? If so then is it ID in column A, Date in column B and the first data starts from row 3?

Comment: Row 3, ColA for IDs and Col B for dates. Yes you are right.

Comment: @Valiant Ok I have edited my code, please try that. Note: This is untested since I have off my computer. Let me know if there is any error.

Comment: Yeah it seems like there is an problem because when i run the code it does not run. Just pressing the run button nothing happens.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235666/discussion-between-raymond-wu-and-valiant).